# .htaccess issue (500 - Internal Server Error) error

Tags: htaccess, redirects, windows, http-code-500, wamp

I was trying to learn how to edit and make a `.htaccess` file using a tutorial found at [corz.org](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php), I copied an existing `.htaccess` file from another site on my localhost and pasted the following content in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $a.php [NC]
```

I was trying to learn how to redirect HTML pages to some PHP page.

**My questions are:**

1. I tried doing Right Click > New > Text Document > Renaming it ".htaccess".  It should work but it gave an error that I must provide file name. But when I pasted `.htaccess` file here it was pasted successfully... Why is this? the same rules should apply to `.htaccess` file and it should generate some error.
2. I have pasted the exact code and checked for any space UN-intentionally left, but still internal server error 500 occurs. Why is this?

Note: I am using Microsoft Windows and Wamp version 2.2

Comment: 1) are you using windows? and are you in the shell? 2) maybe you have weird char (like bad copy and paste)

Comment: i am using notepad for the purpose, and no shell

Comment: There's nothing in that `.htaccess` snippet itself that would trigger a 500 error, except maybe if mod_rewrite is not enabled or something? Whenever you get a 500 error you need to check the server's error log for the details of the error. (`$a` would just be seen as a literal string.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

# check if the file don't exists then redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

and it works fine, the `$a` should be `$1`.

- `RewriteEngine On` Enables the rewrite engine *IF* mod_rewrite is enabled.
- `RewriteBase /` Executes all the rules from the root (`/`) directory.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

- `^` means Starts with.
- `(.*)` means everything. Although, I prefer using `([a-z0-9_\-]+)` which only allows letters, numbers, underscores and dashes
- `$1` means the first matching regular expression that the rule found.

Comment: would you please expalin the code to help me learn my mistake?

Comment: used your code, but its not working

Comment: Absolutely, i'll update my answer

Comment: 1) is the .htaccess at the root? can you give me an example of the file you are calling?

Comment: i have myweb folder (www\zaf) and i created .htaccess file here in zaf, now i have tried to paste the same file in (www) folder, but still same probelm..and two lined code is my htaccess file, as i am trying to learn it

Comment: oh ok, remove the `RewriteBase /`

Comment: still the same issue and thanks for explaining the code to me

Comment: you have no other .htaccess in any other folders? only in zaf? `www` is the webroot like www.domain.com goes to `www`?

Comment: yes, www is just like www.domain.com and now i have two htaccess, one in zaf and other is in www itself...

Comment: ok can you show me both of .htaccess maybe one conflict with the other one.

Comment: both are the same. i copied. but for now, i have deleted .htaccess located at root  as it was applying same error on all other sights located in my localhost

Comment: ok now you only have the .htaccess in the `/zaf/` folder? the rule will change depending where you want to put it.